# Pygame not responding when I press the T key

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am making a program that is supposed to print 'travel' when the `T` key is pressed. But when I press `T`, nothing is printed out, unlike it is supposed to.

My detection code:

```py
        elif keep_doing_current_event and event.type == draw_intro_text_line_1_event:
            typewrite("今天是2121年5月22日。一百年前的今天，天问一号任务火星车“祝融号”")

            text = font.render("（按空格键继续）", True, (255, 255, 255))
            screen.blit(text, (550, 500))

            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if key[K_SPACE]:
                screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
                keep_doing_current_event = False
                screen.blit(city_bg, (0, 0))

                if key[K_t]:
                    print("travel")
```

I have two questions:

1. Can the code ever make it to the `if key[K_t]` statement?
2. If so, is it the `keep_doing_current_event = False` line that is causing it?

(Extra info: First, some text is typwrited out. Then, when the space key is pressed, the background switches to a mars city background. Finally, when the `T` key is pressed, the program should print `travel`)

Comment: It can get to `if key[K_t]`, but only if the spacebar is pressed simultaneously. Is that what you wanted to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code you need to press <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>t</kbd> at once, to print "travel".

You need to draw the background in the application loop. Use `KEYDOWN` event to change the state of `keep_doing_current_event`. Draw the scene depending on `keep_doing_current_event`:

```py
current_background = .... # what ever

# application loop
while True:

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                keep_doing_current_event = False            
    
    if keep_doing_current_event:
    
        # draw keep_doing_current_event scene
  
        # [...]
        
        typewrite("今天是2121年5月22日。一百年前的今天，天问一号任务火星车“祝融号”")
        text = font.render("（按空格键继续）", True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text, (550, 500))
        
        # [...]
 
    else:
 
       # draw game scene
       screen.blit(city_bg, (0, 0))
         
       key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
       if key[K_t]:
           print("travel")
```